# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/Executor

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to execute the below code but getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/Executor" while running. I have added "Common-Exec jar" file too but it is not working.
Do I need to add any other jar file ??

```
package cross_browser;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class NewTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    String url;

  @BeforeClass
  @Parameters({"browser"})
  public void beforeTest(String browser) {
      url = "https://www.facebook.com";
      if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      }
      if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
      }
      driver.manage().window().maximize();    
  }

  @Test
  public void Test() {
      driver.get(url);
      driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Prateek");
      driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Prateek");
      driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.quit();
  }

}
```

XML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name = "CrossBrowser Testing" parallel = "tests" thread-count ="2">
<test name = "Chrome Testing">
    <parameter name ="browser" value = "chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name = "cross_browser.NewTest"></class>
        </classes>
</test>
<test name = "firefox Testing">
    <parameter name ="browser" value = "firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name = "cross_browser.NewTest"></class>
        </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Must be something wrong with the TestNG installation. What command are you using to execute ?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this dependency, it worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

### NoClassDefFoundError

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** in Java occurs when *Java Virtual Machine* is not able to find a particular class at **runtime** which was available at **compile time**. For example, if we have resolved a *method* call from a *class* or accessing any static member of a *class* and that *class* is not available during **run-time** then *JVM* will throw **NoClassDefFoundError**.

The error you are seeing is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/exec/Executor
```

This clearly indicates that *Selenium* is trying to resolve a particular class at runtime from `org/apache/commons/exec/Executor` which is not accessible/available.

### What went wrong :

You have mentioned of adding **Common-Exec jar** but it seems that the related *Class* or *Methods* were resolved from one source during *Compile Time* which was not available during *Run Time*.

This error occurs if there are presence of multiple sources to resolve the *Classes* and *Methods* through **JDK**/**Maven**/**Gradle** and this situation happens when upgrading with **new JAR** files.

### Solution :

Here are a few steps to solve **`NoClassDefFoundError`** :

- If using *Selenium JARs* within a *Java Project* add only required **External JARs** within the **Java Build Path** and remove the unused/unwanted one.
- Incase using a Build Tool e.g. *Maven* or *Gradle*, **remove** all the **External JARs** from the **Java Build Path**. *Maven* or *Gradle* will download and resolve all the required dependencies.
- If using *Selenium JARs*, either use rather then using **selenium-java-x.y.z** *Java Client* use **selenium-server-standalone-x.y.z.jar** instead which bundles all the required dependencies together.
- Incase using *Maven*, either use **`<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>`** or **`<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`**. Avoid using both at the same time.
- Remove the unwanted other `<dependency>` from **pom.xml**
- Clean you *Project Workspace* within your IDE periodically only to build your project with required dependencies.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe away the OS chores periodically.
- take a *System Reboot*.
- Incase you are executing a *Maven Project* always do **`maven clean`**, **`maven install`** and then **`maven test`**

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, i removed the jar files from class path and added again. and my error doesnt appear again, my code ran and got the result