# Merging DesiredCapabilities with FirefoxOptions in Selenium Webdriver Results in java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting: `NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.merge` when I try launching `Selenium WebDriver`:

My code in `main` calls a single method:

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriverProfile().getTMPFirefoxProfile(null); // Parameter is optional
```

I am posting my code in detail in the hope that perhaps someone will be able to offer a suggestion to guide me in the right direction.

**Stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.merge(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions;
    at webdriverX.WebDriverProfile.getTMPFirefoxProfile(WebDriverProfile.java:286)
    at n.NMain.main(NMain.java:22)
```

The call to `getTMPFirefoxProfile(ProxyPOJO proxyPOJO)` calls the code:

```
public WebDriver getTMPFirefoxProfile(ProxyPOJO proxyPOJO) throws InterruptedException, MalformedObjectNameException, InstanceNotFoundException, ReflectionException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", GlobalVar.geckdriverExecutableFilePath); // Verified path is correct via syso


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    if (proxyPOJO != null) {

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyPOJO.getProxyIP() + ":" + proxyPOJO.getProxyPort());
        proxy.setFtpProxy(proxyPOJO.getProxyIP() + ":" + proxyPOJO.getProxyPort());
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyPOJO.getProxyIP() + ":" + proxyPOJO.getProxyPort());


        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    }


    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();


    FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.merge(dc);


    opt.addPreference("dom.popup_maximum", 200);
    opt.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false); 


    opt.merge(capabilities);

    WebDriver driver = WebDriverX.getNewFireFoxWebDriver(opt);      



    return driver;
}
```

The call to: `getNewFireFoxWebDriver(FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions)` calls this code:

```
if (firefoxOptions != null) {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
} else {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

 return driver;
```

I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070242/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxoptions-mergeca) however I've now tried almost 10 different suggestions - none of which solved my problem.

Below I will outline the steps I took to try to solve the problem:

**1)** Right clicked project -> Maven clean -> Maven build -> Maven test (I tried each one separately and then all one after the next)

**2)** Clicked Project -> clean

**3)** Confirmed Firefox is updated to latest version (version 72)

**4)** Removed the library `guava` (the only suggested conflict) from project POM

**5)** Shutdown and restarted Eclipse

**6)** Deleted all run configurations and ran project from scratch

**7)** Re-downloaded GeckoDriver v0.26.0 to make sure I have the lestest version installed

**8)** I Made sure my **POM** file contains `Selenium` dependency version `3.141.591` which contains `merge` method

I'm out of options.. What do I try next?

Below is the contents of the project `POM` file:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.abdn</groupId>
        <artifactId>SimpleNLG</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I have two other projects linked in the build path of this project. From one project, I am able to call `getTMPFirefoxProfile(ProxyPOJO proxyPOJO)` without any issues. From the other one, I get the same error I get with current project. What does this mean? I analyzed the other project and I don't see any conflicting dependencies.

I spent the entire day trying to troubleshoot the issue but I feel completely lost..

**Any ideas?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After covering up all the possible issues and solution on this issue in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070242/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxoptions-mergeca) seems you are quite close now.

Further, I would suggest to install [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) libraries for Java using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) you should add the `<selenium-java>` dependency in your project `pom.xml` first as it would support running your automation project with all Selenium supported browsers.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Moving further, if you want to run tests only in *Firefox*, you can replace with the `selenium-firefox-driver` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Debanjan_B I added `selenium-java` to `POM` file to no avail. I suspect that `Java` is loading a previous version of Selenium due to transitive dependency of project in build path. However, every other project compiles to version `3.141.59`. How can I confirm this? Also,  the exact same method call works flawlessly in another project - and the other project has all of the same projects (+ others) in it's build path. If it's indeed a question of transitive dependency, wouldn't it effect all projects equally? Why would exception be thrown from one, not the other? Thanks for being so helpful!!

Comment: @Debanjan_B  I wish to add that I confirmed `Selenium` complies to version `3.141.59` via `Dependency Hierarchy` in `Maven`. `Maven` shows `[compile]` next to this version. Is it possible `Maven` is showing `compile` next to the wrong version? If yes, how can I know? Also, I know that one project (indirectly referenced through build path of current project) has a library named [`AShot`] which relies on `Selenium Remote Driver version 2.5.3`. However, `Maven` says it is `omitted for conflict with version 3.141.59`. Moreover, the call to `getTMPFirefoxProfile()` actually works in that project..

Comment: @Debanjan_B After much troubleshooting I finally arrived at a solution. I created a new Library named `Project_Libs` Inside the Library I added Jar files of Selenium version `3.141.59`. Right clicked on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path and added `Project_Libs` as Library to project. However, this alone did not solve my problem. In `Order and Export` panel I had to move `Project_Libs` up above another Library named `Libs` (below the `Maven` Library). I also had to manually add `Guava` Jars to this Library. Now it works!! Is there a way to avoid all this in the future?

Comment: @AlanCook It won't be a good idea for me to comment further in case you are having [**transitive dependency**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency) for multiple maven based projects, without seeing the error logs/exceptions or understanding them. However there is a chance of the shared jars getting corrupted for specific environments (os).

Comment: @AlanCook About your current solution: I won't be comfortable with that either as I suspect more conflicts surfacing in the form of [NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465550/nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-os-commandline-findexecutableljava-lang/50469053#50469053) or [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622195/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-exec-executor/49623324#49623324) surfacing when you would least expect them. Anyways, glad to know you have nailed the issue for the time being.